# Build a big data_frame iterating other data_frames

Tags: r

I have a series of files structured as follow:

```
File A
chr1    Start1    End1
.
.
.
chrn    Startn    Endn

File B
chr1    Start1    End1
.
.
.
chrn    Startn    Endn

File n
chr1    Start1    End1
.
.
.
chrn    Startn    Endn
```

the length of the different files is not the same. I'd like to have a data_frame (or any other suitable solution) like:

```
df$File_A
df$File_B
df$File_C
```

and then:

```
>print(df$File_A[1,])
>chr1   Start1     End 
>print(df$File_C[n,]) 
>chrn   Startn     End
```

The problem, as far as I understand is that the files don't have the same length and I can't build a DB.

So far I wrote:

```
library(tidyverse)

where_are_data = "~/Desktop/proof/" 
file.names <- dir(where_are_data, pattern =".bed")

data_frame_promoters <- data.frame()

for (promoter_file in 1:length(file.names)) 
{
a <- str_split(string = file.names[promoter_file], '_')   
b <- a[[1]][1]   
data_1 <- read_tsv(
paste0(where_are_data, file.names[promoter_file]), 
col_names = c("Chromosome","Start","End"))   
name_df_column <- paste0('data_frame_',b)   
assign(name_df, data_1)   
data_frame_promoters$name_df <- rbind(data_frame_promoters$name_df, data_1) 
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "name_df", value = list(Chromosome = c("chr12",  : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 0
```

Do you have any suggestion on how set the data_frame (or any other structure) to get around this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your .bed files are tab-separated format with exactly 3 columns with the same types of data, and with the first row as a column names header, then the following should do what you're looking for.  The lapply will read-in all the .bed files using read.table and tab sep \t and specify their column names as set by col.names.  Strings not set as factors.  Each individual dataset will be saved in to the resultant list 'datasets'.  do.call() function calls the rbind() function, passing to it each element of the list.  The result is a unified data.frame

```
where_are_data = "~/Desktop/proof/" 
file.names <- dir(where_are_data, pattern =".bed")
datasets <- lapply(file.names,FUN=read.table,sep='\t',stringsAsFactors=F,col.names=c("Chromosome","Start","End"),header=T)
df<-do.call(rbind,datasets)
```